# Can a pregnant woman travel 30 minutes when she is only 10 days pregnant?

Tags: obstetrics, risks, travel, 1st-trimester, embryo

If a woman is pregnant for only a week after she misses her period, can she travel 10 to 15 kilometers (6.2 to 9.3mi) in a car?

Will travelling 10 kilometers affect the embryo?

Comment: Are you only asking about the first 10 or so days of pregnancy or at any time during the pregnancy?

Comment: I know women who traveled by car regularly for thirty minutes while pregnant. However, if the woman has any concerns she should consult her doctor/physician. What are the conditions of travel--you already said by car, but over what terrain? How long will the woman remain at the destination? What activity is being done at the destination? Will the same travel be made as a return trip identical to the departing trip? These are questions for additional information that will affect the quality of the answer you receive. Again, good reason to have a conversation with your healthcare providers.

Answer (score 2):

**Pregnancy is not a disability!**

Other than avoiding things known to be bad for a developing fetus such as alcohol, smoking and certain drugs, there really aren't many limits on what you can do. Until a doctor tells you otherwise, feel free to walk those 10-15 kilometers if you want. Or ride a bicycle. Or drive a car. All are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a pregnant woman can travel without most limitations even until the day of birth. The key considerations as the pregnancy progresses is to make sure that accessibility to clinical care is not impeded. For example, I don't recommend going into deepest darkest Africa when you are nine months pregnant.

With that said, pregnant women are at special risk for developing some conditions. One risk is for deep vein thrombosis, which is a life-threatening clot in deep veins that can lead to death. Due to the weight of the fetus, it can compress some deep veins in the pelvis and impede circulation. As a result, I highly recommend that pregnant women (and all people in general), take breaks every hour, get up and stretch, and walk around a little bit.

With this advice, you should be able to drive a few miles or even a few hours - as long as you periodically take breaks and get the blood flowing.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No.

Short Distance Travel is not contraindicated in early pregnancy / first trimester. The embryo is safely implanted in the womb and does not get affected by physical exertion or travel.

I understand your anxiety, but Obstetricians advise that pregnant women go about doing whatever they normally do every day without as much as possible till the third trimester where one needs to adjust for weight and lower physical dexterity.

Comment: This answer might be very helpful to the OP and other users, but it still [needs reliable references](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) to match Health SE standards :-). You can always [edit] your answer to add some. Thanks!